# Python: string.replace("\'","'") after reading txt file

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

When opening and reading a file containing the mark ' (like in the word shouldn't), python replaces it with \' (which ends up being shouldn\'t). I tried running the following code:

```
a=open("file.txt")
b=a.read()
b=b.replace("\'", "'")
```

But b remains the same after running the third line, maybe because it reads "\'" as if it were "'". Please help.

Comment: Python doesn't do that. It might show the string like that if you print it's representation (if it also contains `"`s), but it won't add backslashes to the actual data.

Comment: Agreed with @Lattyware, just tested with the interactive python3 interpreter and it does not do that at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"\'" is the same as "'". The backslash escapes the ' so it doesn't do its special function. That feature is useful if you have a single quoted string.
For example the string '"shouldn\'t"' is printed as "shouldn't".

```
Python 3.3.0 (default, Dec 22 2012, 21:02:07) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = 'shouldn't'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = 'shouldn't'
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> a = 'shouldn\'t'
>>> a
"shouldn't"
>>> a = '"shouldn\'t'
>>> a
'"shouldn\'t'
>>> print(a)
"shouldn't
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to double the slash:

```
b=b.replace("\\'", "'")
```

or use a `r""` raw string literal:

```
b=b.replace(r"\'", "'")
```

Without the doubled slash or raw string literal, the `\'` is interpreted as an espace code meaning `'`.

Do doublecheck that you are not looking at a string representation where python *represents* `'` characters using the escape code:

```
>>> '"' + "'"
'"\''
>>> print '"' + "'"
"'
```

In the above example I create a string with both a double and a single quote character (`"'`) and Python echoes that back to me as a string representation. Using `print` prints the actual string contents and not a representation. Note how Python has escaped the `'` quote for me there.